# php print string returned from function

Tags: php, function, return

I have a set of php functions designed to return error text if they fail. They aren't returning the text. My function looks like this:

```
function poop(){
    $stuff = stuff;
    $things = things;
    if($stuff != stuff){
        return 'e: stuff does not equal stuff!';
    }
    if($things != things){
        return 'e: things do not equal things!';
    }
    // if we got this far all is good!
    return true;

}
```

I call my function in code like so:

```
if(poop() === true){
    // do things that require poop
} else {
    echo poop();
}
```

I thought this would return the 'e:' string as a string and print it to the page in the event that poop() did not return a boolean true value, but in reality it is not. I'm wondering if this is because of a fault in the remainder of my code or if this functionality doesn't actually exist in PHP? How should I go about ensuring I have an error returned from all my function checks? Should I use echo instead of return to print it as a string on the page?

Comment: Protip: `foo` or `bar`, not `poop`.

Comment: Don't understand the issue but in any case you should do `$result = poop(); if ($result === true){}else{ echo $result;}` instead of calling the func twice

Comment: poop joke never gets old

Comment: I read the question 3 times already and I'm still not sure if I understood it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what you're asking, either.  I'm not even sure your code would compile.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan Pretty sure it wouldn't, it's PHP.

Comment: I assume it's just pseudo-code

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is if I use `return` in a function can I directly print the returned string? If I can than it must be something else in my code that is sucking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call your function more than once. Save its return value in a variable:

```
$ret = poop();
if ($ret === true) {
    // Do things that require the success.
} else {
    // Log your error message here:
    echo "An error occurred: ".$ret;
    logMessage($ret);
    // etc.
}
```

You may also want to look into [PHP exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) for a potentially cleaner  — but probably slower — solution to error handling.

Comment: A shorter version: `if(($res = poop()) === true) { /**/ } else { echo $res; }`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if( poop() !== TRUE )
    echo poop();
```

I used it on this code:

```
function poop(){ 
    $stuff = 'stuff'; 
    $things = 'things'; 
    // this is where we have wrong value
    if($stuff != 'stuff1'){ 
        return 'e: stuff does not equal stuff!'; 
    } 
    if($things != 'things'){ 
       return 'e: things do not equal things!'; 
    } 
    // if we got this far all is good! 
    return true; 

}
```

I hope I goood understood you, I'm newby in PHP too. :)
It is also good practice to throw an exception instead of returning error msg string.